# Close bootstrap model popup from another controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-broadcast

Hi i have a controllerA which generate a form based on some URL parameters and after submitting that form some some action will be performed.  Now i have created another controllerB and in that i have created a button. upon clicking on that button one model popup will be opened which contains controllerA url as iframe src.
In that model popup i'm able to see the form generated. After submitting that form i have to close the model popup.

controllerA

```
  - Contains some logic to generate form
```

controllerB

```
  - Contains a model popup with embed iframe. iframe src as controllerA URL
```

Here is my question
        How can i close that model afer submitting the form?

Here is sample code:

this code contains in controllerB

```
  $scope.addmemPopup = function() {
        $scope.showpopup = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'addmem.tpl.html',
            size: 'lg',
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
            windowClass: 'add-mem'
        });
  }

  $scope.getIframeurl = function() {
        return '#/genmem/?mem_id='+$scope.mem.id+'&z_id=' + $scope.mem.zip;
  };
  $scope.hidePopup = function() {
        $scope.showpopup .close();
  };
```

In controllerA i have a method to submit the form. after submitting the form how can i close the above popup which is rendered from controllerB.

I think hopefully i explained correctly. please help me in resolving this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What's the relationship between controllerA and controllerB?
if controllerB is the parent controller,you can use `$scope.$emit('event:close')` in controllerA and receive this event in controllerB with

```
$scope.$on('event:close',function(evt) {
   $scope.showpopup.close();
})
```

Comment: Those are two different controllers. Basically popup initiation starts in controllerB upon clicking on a button. In that popup i'm showing a form with Submit button. after clicking on that the popup has  to close. ControllerA makes a serivice call to submit the data.

Comment: I have a app controller as parent. these controllerA and controllerB are childs to app controller

Comment: you can use $scope.$emit in controller A and receive it with $scope.$on in the parent controller then use $scope.$broadcast in your parent controller  to pass the event to controller A,but I suggest to use the modal with ui-bootstrap for it  has the property to solve your problem  [link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)